# Disable Multiple Selection in JSTree is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I am using JSTree in my application with following code.

```
this.CreateTreeView = function () {
    $('#jstree_demo_div').jstree({
        'core': {
            'multiple': false,
            'data': [
               { "id": "ajson1", "parent": "#", "text": "Simple root node" },
               { "id": "ajson2", "parent": "#", "text": "Root node 2" },
               { "id": "ajson3", "parent": "ajson2", "text": "Child 1" },
               { "id": "ajson4", "parent": "ajson2", "text": "Child 2" },
            ]
        }
    });
}
```

As shown in my code i am trying to disable multiple selection.

Now when i use following code to select node.

```
$("#jstree_demo_div").jstree().select_node("ajson3");
$("#jstree_demo_div").jstree().select_node("ajson4");
```

Still it select both node. So it becomes like multiple selection from Javascript.

**I am putting this question just to confirm that is it correct working of JSTree?**

I know that i can deselect all node before selecting any node using `deselect_all` function.

But according to me if multiple selection is set to false then selecting node from javascript also should select only one node.

Please correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`select_node` will select a node regardless of the `multiple` setting.

The setting only limits user interaction, `select_node` is a lower level method and will not be limited, so you (the developer) can modify the selection programmatically without limitation.

If you want to use the same function that is triggered by user interaction (and is therefore limited by `multiple`) use `activate_node`.

Comment: Hello vakata, Thanks for support. Your library JSTree is really good.

Answer (score 5):

just use this configuration

```
this.CreateTreeView = function () {

    **"plugins" : [
                "checkbox",  
            ],**  

    $('#jstree_demo_div').jstree({
        'core': {
            **'multiple': false,**
            'data': [
               { "id": "ajson1", "parent": "#", "text": "Simple root node" },
               { "id": "ajson2", "parent": "#", "text": "Root node 2" },
               { "id": "ajson3", "parent": "ajson2", "text": "Child 1" },
               { "id": "ajson4", "parent": "ajson2", "text": "Child 2" },
            ]
        },

        **'checkbox' : {            
            'deselect_all': true,
             'three_state' : false, 
        }**

    }); }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
'checkbox' : {            
 'deselect_all': true,
 'three_state' : false, 
}
```

works fine!

Answer (score 0):

To Disable checkbox multi-select in JStree this code also work perfectly  :

```
   var tmp=null;   /// to prevent recursion
              treeobj.on("check_node.jstree uncheck_node.jstree", function(e, data)                 {
                    if(tmp!=data.node.id){      
                        tmp=data.node.id;
                        treeobj.jstree("uncheck_all", null);
                        treeobj.jstree("check_node",data.node.id);
                    }
                })
```